# Flask-WTF form doesn't have attribute 'validate_on_submit'

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask-WTF to validate a form when submitted.  I am using `form.validate_on_submit()`, but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'PickASong' object has no attribute 'validate_on_submit'
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flask import redirect
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import *
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import Form, TextField, BooleanField, PasswordField, TextAreaField, validators

class PickASong(Form):
    song = TextField(u'Song title', validators=[DataRequired()])

class PickAnumber(Form):
    songNumber = IntegerField(u'Please select song number', validators=[DataRequired()])

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=["POST","GET"])
def hello():
    form = PickASong(csrf_enabled=False)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = form.song.data
        print user
        d=str(user)
        print d
        # search(d)
        cmd = "python Search.py --q \"" + d +'"'
        os.system(cmd)
        return redirect('/2')

    return render_template('searchtwo.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported `from flask.ext.wtf import Form`, and then subsequently imported `from wtforms import *`, which includes the base WTForms `Form`.  So the name `Form` refers to the last object bound to it, `wtforms.Form`.  This is the reason you avoid `import *`.  A quick fix is to move `from flask_wtf import Form` below `from wtforms import *`.  The correct fix is to import only what you need, rather than everything.  If you need both forms, alias one import so the names don't conflict: `from flask_wtf import Form as FlaskForm`.

You have redundantly written the following imports below the large import block at the top.

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import Form, TextField, BooleanField, PasswordField, TextAreaField, validators
```

Simply do not import `Form` from `wtforms`, or reverse the two lines, to effect the immediate fix.

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField, PasswordField, TextAreaField, validators
```